# How do we track clicks on ads served with embedded JavaScript tags?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Some of our advertisers require us to serve their ads from their server using embedded JavaScript tags so that they can track impressions and clicks.

My question is, how do WE track the clicks they have had on their ads, so we can tell how their campaign is going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer is actually the way OpenX does it.
http://www.openx.org/docs/whitepapers/3rd-party-click-tracking

Basically it searches the Javascript for the click the link and replaces it with a bounce (redirect) link that allows it track the click and still deliver the user.

It is slightly inflexible as it depends on the third party tracking code, but it is probably the 'cleanest' solution.

Comment: I worked for an Ad serving company like the Op and this is how I solved it there. That and TOS which restricts JS from the advertiser.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all depends on the javascript code of the advertiser.

Maybe you can add an "onload" function to your page, where you search the page for images. If the image has the properties of the ad, add an eventlistener for the click event with javascript ... then call a server page with javascript which stores the values in a database ... just a quick idea

Answer (score 0):

You could put an invisible layer over the ad and respond to the click by calling Their click after sending you a notice that the ad was clicked (maybe loading a special web bug).  This technique is considered evil since it could easily be used to send the user to somewhere other than the advertiser's page.